# NodeJS Performance wise - run single node file with multiple required VS run multiple node files

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm building a project where the backend consists of 3 parts:

- `message-process.js` - Get new messages every 1 sec => process the data => add new item to the DB
- `events-process.js` - Listen to the DB until there is a new item in DB => process the item => might add a new item to DB
- `stats-process.js` - Listen to the DB until there is a new item in DB => process the item => might add a new item to DB

Is there any performance difference if I run each file like this:

```
node message-process.js
node events-process.js
node stats-process.js
```

VS

Export from each file the main function and then build an `index.js` file:

```js
const main-func1 = require('./message-process.js');
const main-func2 = require('./events-process.js');
const main-func3 = require('./stats-process.js');

console.log('staring main func1...');
main-func1();
console.log('staring main func2...');
main-func2();
console.log('staring main func3...');
main-func3();
```

Then running the single `index.js` file:

```
node index.js
```

Is there any a decline in performance in one of the options? There is any 'best practice'?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to tell which is more performant is to try both options and measure them.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, dont use `-` instead use [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for naming

you wrote a structured synchronous code so that will execute funct1 then will wait until ends its execution then will execute func2 and so on... it will not execute them at the same time. if you want to do that you must use [Node Workers](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: The name of the files is just an example. I don't need them to run at the same time, but once I run them they listen for changes in the DB and only then act